# How to create a User Control on button click in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

The control that I want to use is already registered in my page.

```
 <%@ Register Src="~/MEDCONTROLS/statform.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="statform" %>
```

and i am displaying it in my page using this code. (using different id's && different TempHosp#)

```
<uc1:statform runat="server" TempHospNum="ER101" ID="statform1" />
<uc1:statform runat="server" TempHospNum="ER102" ID="statform2" />
<uc1:statform runat="server" TempHospNum="ER103" ID="statform3" />
```

Now what I need to do is, on the click button event, it will create a new user control, actually same user control but only different id and different property eg.

EDIT

```
  Protected Sub btnAddUserControl_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddUserControl.Click

     'Generate user control with a TempHospnum = "ER104" and id="statform4"
  End Sub
```

Now it is adding BUT in page.init only, NOT on Button_click

```
'NOT WORKING
 Protected Sub btnNewBed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewBed.Click
     Dim myControl As statform = Page.LoadControl("~/MEDCONTROLS/statform.ascx")
     myControl.ID = "statform13"
     myControl.TempHospNum = "ER113"
     myControl.ERBedNumber = "Bed13"
     form1.Controls.Add(myControl)
     myControl.Visible = True

 End Sub

'This is working but this is not what I needed
 Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
     Dim myControl As statform = Page.LoadControl("~/MEDCONTROLS/statform.ascx")
     myControl.ID = "statform13"
     myControl.TempHospNum = "ER113"
     myControl.ERBedNumber = "Bed13"
     form1.Controls.Add(myControl)
     myControl.Visible = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable which references the class name of the user control, and use Page.LoadControl.

You can interact with any properties you add to the user control class definition.

```
dim myControl as YourUserControlClassName = Page.LoadControl("~/yourlayoutfilepath/yourUserControlFile.ascx")
myControl.ID="stratFormX"
Me.Controls.Add(myControl)
```

Comment: how can i display the generated user control on my page @trucker_jim?

Comment: Me.Controls.Add(myControl)

Comment: i already added that on my button click event but there is no new User Control displaying...

Comment: It may be appearing at the bottom of the page. You need to add it to the right place on your page...

Comment: What i observed is when my code is placed on Click event, nothing happens. BUT when i placed my code inside Page_Init, it added. Why?

Comment: Good question...I added mine during button click and it added no problem. It's to do with the page lifecycle in some way.

Comment: I have to say with my experience of dynamic controls, it's best to add them during oninit. That poses a problem because event handlers haven't fired at that point...so you can compare the Page.Request("__EVENTTARGET") and compare it to the unique id of the button to see if it's been clicked.

Comment: But, I think I've answered your basic question...how to add a user control dynamically

Comment: My question is to create a User Control on button click event, so, my query is not yet answered. I will try you suggestion. Thanks :)